# python numpy core _methods.py MemoryError

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am getting following error in numpy when trying to fit a data. Can anyone suggest how to fix this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wolverine\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\naive_bayes\naive_bayes\nb_author_id.py", line 32, in <module>
    clf.fit(train, labels)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 175, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 332, in _partial_fit
    epsilon = 1e-9 * np.var(X, axis=0).max()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3093, in var
    keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 101, in _var
    x = asanyarray(arr - arrmean)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#MemoryError